# I have a big delay before we can see purchases in google analytics 4

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

I created an e-commerce connection via GTM. I’m sending data via dataLayer on the thank_you_page. After that, I’m sending data to Google Analytics 4. I can see purchases in GTM, also I can see purchases in GA4 debugging (Configure --> DebugView) at that moment. I can see that purchases are registered and I can see their parameters but I have a big delay before we can see it in a report (Report --> Monetization --> E-commerce purchases). A delay is something around 6-12 hours or even more. Is it okay? Can you help me with this problem? How can we see purchases in reports without a delay(or around 1 hour). Or it’s a normal delay for a GA?
Maybe I can fix it?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It's a **very norma**l situation for this.
You can see the data shows in real-time report and debug view immediately.
But if you want to see in report.

You will need to wait until GA processed the data.

In the Reports Snapshot (Report -> Monetization -> E-commerce purchases) it may take 1-4 hours according to the docs (personally I've seen up to 12 hours delay) and for the Explore custom reports it might take 24-48 hours.

What I usually do to debug is:

1. Expect up to 48 hours to debug a scenario / end 2 end flow.
2. Use the DebugView to quickly check the incoming events.
3. Use whatever reports I can to make sure they are being stitched up correctly (i.e. purchase events to get stitched with the proper user/client)
4. Finalize verification with custom reports after a day or two.

So basically it is very long process to introduce changes with some of the events with GA4, it wasn't like that with UA. :/

This is the [document](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9333790?hl=en#:%7E:text=Many%20of%20your%20reports%20and,your%20website%20or%20app%20successfully.) for GA4.
And that's another one for [data freshness](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/11198161?hl=en), which doesn't really say which types of reports or features are delayed with each of the Intervals, but it gives you an idea of the Intervals they work with internally.